# Implementing Button Click in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am missing `TButton.Click` Method in FireMonkey `TButton`.

Is there any way to fire click event in the code in fire monkey? If there is no such event, just use the click method to fire the action assigned to the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this method : 
first declare this new type to access TButton Click procedure  :

```
type
  TButtonHack = type TButton;
```

Then caste your button to TButtonHack class and call Click procedure  :

```
TButtonHack(Button1).Click;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your solution Mahdi.
I am talking about Firemonky. TButton in Firemonkey doesn't have Click method.

Comment: @Oussama It does. It's protected. This is the standard protected member access hack.

Comment: Yes. I upvoted. Event though you originally accepted my answer, this is probably the right answer to the question that you asked. I do wonder why you want to invoke on click events.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can simply write:

```
Button1.OnClick(Button1);
```

If there is an action attached to the button you can invoke it with

```
Button1.Action.Execute;
```

But that is not really to be recommended. The right way to do this is to create a method to do the work. Then call that method from either your `OnClick` event handler, or the other location in your code that wants to invoke this action. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
begin
  // do whatever it is
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoSomething;
end;
```

Then anywhere in your code you can just call `DoSomething`. It's best to leave GUI event handlers just for handling GUI events.

Comment: Thanks David,
But in my situation there is no actual code. I link the button to a standard action (ChangeTabItem).
In my code, in a particular execution path i want the ChangeTabItem to execute.
I am aware of the .Execute & ExectureTarget Methods of the class, but I wander why not to link it the button it self, so if I change the code related to the button, I don't need to re-code.
I hope I made my case clear. I am not sure.

Comment: You can call Execute on the action I suppose. When you assign an action to a button, doesn't the OnClick event also get assigned?

Comment: not explicitly!
Anyway, I'll stick to your method of "Do Something"... I think this is the best idea.